# How to solve a "tensor equation"?

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, tensors

I am trying to solve equations which looks like this:

$$
T_{ab} - T_{bc} = a_1 T_{ab} + a_2 T_{ac} + a_3 T_{bc},
$$

where $T_{xy}$ are tensors. I want to get the $a_i$'s (in this simple example $a_1=1$, $a_2=0$, $a_3=-1$).

The problem is that the Mathematica solving routines (`Solve`, `LinearSolve`) divide the equation by $T_{xy}$ to obtain a solution (or solutions), which is (or some of them are), in turn, not a solution (solutions).

What I tried to circumvent this problem:
I know (from the construction of my equation) that all $a_i$'s are element $\{-1,0,1\}$. So I tried to set the domain to integers. But this gives me lots of condidtional solutions (like `if Tab=integer, then...`) which I don't want.

Of course I could solve the above example equation by hand, but in the end I will need to solve a few hundred equations of this type with 70 tensors or so.

Thanks in advance for any attempt to help me!

Anton

Comment: You appear to misunderstand basic _Mathematica_ syntax. Start learning documentation on the new tensor functionality in _ver.9_. For earlier versions this post might be helpful: [How to calculate scalar curvature Ricci tensor and Christoffel symbols in Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/how-to-calculate-scalar-curvature-ricci-tensor-and-christoffel-symbols-in-mathem/8908#8908). For solving matrix equations see e.g. [General form of a linear transformation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37172/general-form-of-a-linear-transformation/37174#37174).

Comment: No, I do not misunderstand basic Mathematica syntax. But, what you couldn't know: I am working with an older special package that forces me to use Mathematica 8 and a special syntax. (And I necessarily need that package.)

Comment: Really ? So why don't you use correct `Mathematica` notation, but something like `a_1 `, `a_2` etc?

Comment: In my Mathematica code I write T[a,b] and a[i] etc. I just wanted to give an as simple as possible example that illustrates my problem. In the future, I'll not change the notation, or should I?

Comment: You should always provide valid `Mathematica` code. So if you have different notation in your notebook you can edit your question to make it correct. By the way I didn't vote down your question, I find questions on tensors interesting.

Comment: Okay, many thanks :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need to use any specific tensor functionality. [SolveAlways](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SolveAlways.html) seems to suffice:

```
SolveAlways[ T1 - T3 == a1 T1 + a2 T2 + a3 T3, {T1, T1, T3} ]
(* => {{a1 -> 1, a2 -> 0, a3 -> -1}} *)
```

Comment: This solution works fine unless you have large equations. Then Mathematica needs an tremendous amount of memory. So you need to "help" Mathematica... the following worked for me (basically, I split up the "tensor" eq into one equation for each tensor):

Comment: I created a new answer due to the length limit for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

please read the comment below the answer that I marked as solved

```
 (* put all the terms to one side of the eq *)
tensorEq = -(T1 - T3) + 
  a1 T1 + a2 T2 + a3 T3
(* collect the terms that belong together *)
tensorTermsList = 
 Apply[List, Collect[tensorEq, {T1, T2, T3}]]
(* set the terms individually to 0 *)
tensorEqsList = 
 Table[tensorTermsList[[i]] == 0, {i, 1, Length[tensorTermsList]}]
(* now we can give the full list to SolveAlways, SolveAlways can 
handle a large number of simple equations *)
sol = 
 SolveAlways[tensorEqsList, {T1, T2, T3}][[1]]
```