# Control over the way matrix is displayed

Tags: equation-solving, output-formatting, linear-algebra

I am wondering how to change the output format in *Mathematica*. For example, I have $x=\binom{3}{1}$ and $y=\binom{2}{5}$, and I want to find what linear combination of $x$ and $y$ produces $\binom{7}{11}$. What do I have to do to make *Mathematica* display the output  $x+2y$ ?

I tried using `Solve`, but *Mathematica* just returns the coefficients. I also tried to use the augmented matrix, but again *Mathematica* still did not give me the output I want.

P.S. I am working with a 16 by 16 matrix with 16 variables, so it's not very convenient to read off the coefficients for each variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [General form of a linear transformation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37172/general-form-of-a-linear-transformation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x = {3, 1}
y = {2, 5}
a  Defer[x] + b Defer[y] /. First@Solve[a x + b y == {7, 11}, {a, b}]

(* x + 2 y *)
```

Note that the output is usable as such: evaluate it and you'll get the combination result.

If only integer coefficients are desired, changing the `Solve` to something like:

```
Solve[a x + b y == {7, 11} && {a, b} \[Element] Integers, {a, b}]
```

will accomplish this. If you extend things where no solutions, or multiple solutions are possible, probably want to do the `Solve` first, check it, then do the replace.

Edit: Here's a *sketch* (meaning not heavily tested, surely more elegant ways to do same) of how you might generalize this into a function:

```
ClearAll[combo];

SetAttributes[combo, HoldAll]l

combo[a_, b_, c_] := 
 Block[{d = Defer /@ Unevaluated[{a, b}], syms = Table[Unique[], {2}]},
  Total[syms*d] /. First@Solve[Total[{a, b}*(syms)] == c, syms]];

(* cobble up an example *)

m1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
m2 = {{3, 5}, {7, 9}};

(* do some combo *)
result = 3 m1 - 2 m2

(* solve and output as desired *)
combo[m1, m2, result]

(* 3 m1 - 2 m2 *)
```

As above, the result can be used/evaluated. If you go the generalized function route, you probably *do* want to check for no-solution cases, add desired limitation(s) to solve (e.g. integer only), and perhaps extend it to more than two + result arguments...

Comment: Wow that is quick. Thank you very much.